# SQLite + Entity Framework 4.0 + Identity column/Autoinc does not work

Tags: entity-framework, sqlite, identity-column

This is my table:

```
-- Original table schema
CREATE TABLE [SchoolYear] (
    [Start] datetime NOT NULL,
    [End] datetime NOT NULL,
    [Id] integer PRIMARY KEY ON CONFLICT ABORT AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
);
```

My Entity in the EF designer has StoredGeneratedPattern set to Identity OR Compute and datatype is int64.

Everytime I insert a second SchoolYear object I get this error:

> An object with the same key is already in the ObjectStateManager...

Answer (score 3):

Check that the autoincremented property has the StoreGeneratedPattern attribute set to "Identity" in the SSDL part of the model, not in CSDL. 
This is a known issue, the conceptual attribute is not taken into account while generating the code.

Comment: its set to Identity in both: SSDL + CSDL so it should work, but it does NOT!

Comment: without recognizing it earlier I have a new exception now:


System.InvalidOperationException was unhandled:

...The EntityKey property can only be set when the current value of the property is null...

EDIT: Adding a new object to the context works for the first time when I check the table a new row is created, so the autoinc must work. Its something different now!

Comment: What a stupid error that was: (got again a new exception ...) 

I added always the same object to the context that seemed the problem.

 Now it works.

I could have sworn, that EF v1 allowed me to add as many equal objects I wanted without throwing an exception, EF v1 just avoided adding the dupe object. 

Seems that changed in EF v4 ?

Comment: Try dotConnect for SQLite (http://devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite). I have made a test and autoincrement column is read successfully into the inserted objects.